# A representative guides one through the signing of a contract; e.g. internet services. What empowers them to do this? What are they, legally?

Tags: contract-law, adhesion-contracts

I'm looking for some legal terms and concepts related to the empowerment of a representative to guide someone through the signing of a contract. Is there a legal concept for such a person? Specifically, in the case of, e.g., whoever answers one's call in a cellphone company one wants to make a contract with, the representative isn't allowed to, for example, change the adhesion contract, but they do seem empowered to represent the company in the signing of the contract. So it seems to me that they are some sort of representative, but maybe they are legally something less than a "full" representative of the company. What is such a person, legally?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### An [agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_agency)

> a person, called the agent, that is authorized to act on behalf of another (called the principal) to create legal relations with a third party.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Very small follow-up: are people will "full" powers to represent someone (e.g. CEO) agents in the same regard as sales representatives, only in a difference of degree? (Will accept answer when timer allows it)

Comment: Agents can be limited in capacity - a grocery clerk has the capacity to sell you groceries but not sell you the grocery store.

Comment: @shintuku in fact, Agents might not even be allowed to negotiate but only accept the terms their superiors dictated, e.g. the clerk can't sell you the milk for 1$ when the price sticker is 2$.